# The result by haversine formula is meter o kmeter?

Tags: formula, distance, haversine

I use the haversine formula to calculate the distance among the points. The result of this formula is in meter or in kmeter?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It gives you the same unit that you gave it in the radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haversine formula is used for finding distance between to points, if latitude and longitude for both points are known.

**Formula:**

ACOS(SIN(Lat1)*SIN(Lat2) +COS(Lat1)*COS(Lat2)*COS(Lon2-Lon1)) *6371

**Excel formula:**

=ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) *COS(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) +SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat1)) *SIN(RADIANS(90-Lat2)) *COS(RADIANS(Long1-Long2))) *6371

**Note:**

Replace 6371 with 3958.756 if you want the answer in miles.

**For further detail:**

http://bluemm.blogspot.in/2007/01/excel-formula-to-calculate-distance.html

Comment: This is not the haversine formula, it's the spherical law of cosines formula. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Comment: If your Haversine formula uses...

- 6,371, the units are kilometers
- 6,371,000, the units are meters
- 3,958, the units are miles